# Switch case inside While loop

Tags: jsp

Is it possible to put swicthcase inside While loop? I'm trying but I cant pass the value to another page, it only displays null

```
<form action="NewFile1.jsp" method="get">
Birthday: <br>
<%! int i = 1, j; 
    String mon = "";%>
<%
    out.println("<select name='month'>");
    while(i <= 12) {
        out.print("<option>" + i + "</option>");
        i++;
    }
    out.print("</select>");



%>  


    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Page to output the selected value in combo box

```
<body>
<%
//String mo = request.getParameter("month");
String mo = "";
switch(request.getParameter("month")) {
case "1": mo =  "January"; break;

}
%>

<%=out.print("Birthday: " + mo)%>
```

For example, in the combo box are numbers representing the month respectively. If the user selected 2, it should dislpay "February" on the next page.

Comment: In this code I placed the switchcase on the output page. I tried putting it in the NewFile.jsp but it doesnt work. My question is, is it possible to put switch case in the while loop?

Comment: First of all, why are you still using scriptlets? This is 2013. Wake up!

Comment: You're not clear on whether the request parameter returns `null`, or that the `switch` ends up with the `mo` not being set. Please print/debug `request.getParameter("month")` directly before making possibly irrelevant assumptions about the switch. If it's already `null` at that point, then the switch has got nothing to do with the problem. Further, a switch on string works only since Java 1.7, but you would otherwise have gotten a clear JSP compilation error page, which you didn't tell anything about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with int, instead of String:

```
<%
    String mo = "";
    int month = Integer.parseInt("0"+request.getParameter("month"));
    switch(month) {
    case 1: mo =  "January"; break;
        ...
    }
%>

<%=mo%>
```

Comment: getParameter() can return a Array of String or null. To force a use of String, a cast to ""+ is used to prevent a NPE for example. 0 is just the try to prevent NAN or scientific numbers. No real use tougth. At the end in reduces all exceptions down to a NFE.